# Print preview showing distortion in layers from GeoServer via MapFish and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, mapfish

I have an application which shows the print preview before printing the map and the problem is that the layer is distorted in the first image but when I zoom into the map the distortion goes away.

I am using MapFish as the printing module and I assume that OpenLayers deals with the print preview part.

I am new to this so I am not sure if this a code based problem or a setting based problem (either in GeoServer or MapFish)

[image]